# Problem in using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am learning AsyncTask,I tried to print Toast message inside doInBackground method,is it possible to use Toast messages in it?Code is running fine is Toast message is removed..
getting Error as Cant create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got it :)**

```
protected class Asyctast extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>
{

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Log.d("Asynctask", ""+params);  
Looper.prepare();   

         ImageThumbnailsActivity m = new ImageThumbnailsActivity();

            Toast.makeText(ImageThumbnailsActivity.this,""+params ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final Dialog dialog_options = new Dialog(ImageThumbnailsActivity.this);
            dialog_options.setContentView(R.layout.option);
            dialog_options.show();
        Looper.loop();
        return null;

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while your answer suffices, you may be interested to know that the reasons behind why you can't Toast inside the "doInBackground" of an AsyncTask. The purpose of an AsyncTask is to run something to be done in the background. In your case, all of the code you wrote doesn't need to be put in a background thread. Async tasks are used for things like downloading/keeping a forever running loop...etc.  If you REALLY want to use AsyncTask and inject things to the foreground UI thread -- such as Toast -- then you have to do get a reference to the top most Context/Activity, and call:

```
myContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override public void run{
         Toast.....
    }
});
```